# Rendering mathML in a canvas fails on Safari. Image load callback is not triggered

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, mobile-safari, mathml

I'm trying to render mathML into an HTML5 canvas. The best [suggestion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas) so far has been to embed the mathML as an SVG foreign object, render into an image and then render the image into the canvas.

The problem is that this approach works in Firefox but fails in on the iPad.  You can see some examples here:

> Rendering [mathML as SVG](http://webductive.com/examples/svg.html). Works on Firefox and iPad.
>
> Rendering [mathML in the canvas](http://webductive.com/examples/canvas.html). Works on FF. Fails on iPad.
>
> A [debug version of canvas rendering](http://webductive.com/examples/debug_canvas.html). Drawing is delayed until mouseDown.  This allows using [firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) on the iPad.

The code in the canvas.html example is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
        <title>Canvas Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var drawMath = function() {
    // Get the canvas element.
    var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = elem.getContext("2d");
    var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
            "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
            "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:20px'>" +
        "<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML' display='block'>" +
        "<mrow>" +
        "<mi _moz-math-font-style='italic'>x</mi>" +
        "<mo>=</mo>" +
        "<mfrac>" +
        "<mrow>" +
        "<mo>&#x2212;</mo>" +
        "<mi _moz-math-font-style='italic'>b</mi>" +
        "<mo>&#xB1;</mo>" +
        "<msqrt>" +
        "<mrow>" +
        "<msup>" +
        "<mi _moz-math-font-style='italic'>b</mi>" +
        "<mn>2</mn>" +
        "</msup>" +
        "<mo>&#x2212;</mo>" +
        "<mn>4</mn>" +
        "<mi _moz-math-font-style='italic'>a</mi>" +
        "<mi _moz-math-font-style='italic'>c</mi>" +
        "</mrow>" +
        "</msqrt>" +
        "</mrow>" +
        "<mrow>" +
        "<mn>2</mn>" +
        "<mi _moz-math-font-style='italic'>a</mi>" +
        "</mrow>" +
        "</mfrac>" +
        "</mrow>" +
        "</math>" +
            "</div>" +
            "</foreignObject>" +
            "</svg>";
    var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
    mathimg = new Image();
    var svg = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
    mathimg.src = ""; // Trick from http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7731 (Didn't help)
    var drawImg = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(mathimg, 0, 0);
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
    mathimg.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
        drawImg();
    }, false);
    mathimg.src = url;
    };
    drawMath();
});
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas">
      Render some math here
    </canvas>

  </body>
</html>
```

When you run this code in Firefox the image load callback gets invoked. On the iPad, load
doesn't get called and nothing renders.

I've tried a few things including the [suggestion](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7731) to set the image.src explicitly prior to setting the callback.

Also, replacing the load callback with a timer (300 ms delay) doesn't seem to help. The code gets
executed but still nothing renders. Since my target platform is the iPad this is a serious roadblock. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is a new (retina display) iPad running iOS 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'charset=utf-8' from {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"}

```
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml"});
```